# How to create a unix script to loop a Hive SELECT query by taking table names as input from a file?

Tags: shell, unix, hive, hiveql

It's pretty straightforward what I'm trying to do. I just need to count the records in multiple Hive tables.

I want to create a very simple `hql` script that takes a file.txt with table names as input and count the total number of records in each of them:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from <tablename>
```

Output should be like:

```
table1 count1
table2 count2
table3 count3
```

I'm new to Hive and not very well versed in Unix scripting, and I'm unable to figure out how to create a script to perform this.

Can someone please help me in doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Simple working shell script:

```
 db=mydb

 for table in $(hive -S -e "use $db; show tables;") 
 do 
 #echo "$table"
 hive -S -e "use $db; select '$table' as table_name, count(*) as cnt from $table;"
 done
```

You can improve this script and generate file with select commands or even single select with `union all`, then execute file instead of calling Hive for each table.

If you want to read table names from file, use this:

```
for table in filename
do 
...
done
```

Comment: What am I missing? Is there something else that I need to pass to the script?

Comment: Are you executing it in a shell? If you are trying to call beeline (not `hive` cli) from shell script, look at this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/64438/hive-beeline-e-in-shell-script.html

Comment: I'm executing it in a shell.

Comment: After modification, my code is as follows: `for table in table_list
do 
echo "$table"
eval 'hive -e "select count(*) as cnt from dbname.$table;"'
done` and I execute it by calling: `sh loop.sh < list_of_tables.txt` but now it gives me the error: `Line 1:28 Table not found 'table_list' ` Any idea why it's unable to associate the input file with the variable `table_list` in `for` loop? Also, I did not know how to get the table name in the select query, because the quotes gets messed up.

Comment: @LearneR why do you need eval? Script in my answer works, I have tested it. Look also at this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/